# Resource allocation task

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

I'm researching about possibilities to solve about such problem:

I've Tasks, which are described by:

1. Allowed days (when it can be done)
2. Necessary skills to do it
3. Necessary instruments to do it
4. The duration of task (in hours)
5. Profit price for task
6. Forfeit per week if it is not done at last allowed day.

For example: To fix an iron by electrician (skill) with multi-meter(instrument) between 1 and 15 august (allowed days) for 2 hours (task's duration). The price is $10 (profit), but if it is done after 15 august $1 forfeit will be payed for every day after 15 august.

Also I've Worker's resources, which are described by:

1. Day
2. Skills
3. Instruments
4. Day's performance (possible number of working-hours)

For example: An electrician with multi-meter who can work at 2 august for 3 hours.

It is needed to match Tasks with Worker's. Worker's resource must have all skills and instruments that task needs. I want to maximize earnings (profit-forfeit).

Unfortunately, this problem seems to be not able to be led to linear programming problem. (Do I mistake?) So what algorithms would you advice me to research to solve this problem?

Comment: I guess you want to maximize the profit. If so I think you should add this to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use a [Metaheuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic) algorithm to solve this optimization problem. For instance you can use [genetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) since it is easy to understand and implement and it has been made to solve such problems.

Comment: I see this argument more often. Many, many useful MIP models are actually solved using using methods that are non-polynomial. I am sure you don't want to imply all these efforts are non-sensical,

Comment: I am not implying anything, I didn't know it could be solved in polynomial time. However I am pretty sure it is very easy to solve this kind of problems with metaheuristics since their implementations are straightforward. I have no knowledge about MIP. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I beg to differ if you indeed want to maximize profit and want to differ then you can formulate the problem as mixed integer problem (a subset of linear programming in which some variables are integers, possibly binaries). In your example `To fix an iron by electrician (skill) with multi-meter(instrument) between 1 and 15 august (allowed days) for 2 hours (task's duration). The price is $10 (profit), but if it is done after 15 august $1 forfeit will be payed for every day after 15 august.` you can create binary variables for each hour of electrician's schedule assigned to fix an iron between 1st to 15th August, means whether that hour will be spent by electrician for fixing the iron or not. Then you need just two such binary variables to be one, rest zero (in effect two hour).

PS: I am 100% confident that this could be formulated as MIP problem (with my 9+ years of exp in this area), per your question you are asking for suggestion around this.

Comment: I edited my answer. I didn't know it could be solved in polynomial time.